# title placement in mobile apps

Tags: mobile, jquerymobile, header, title

What's best practice for placing page titles in mobile development?

In jquerymobile [it looks like header is great placement](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/pages/docs-pages.html), however titles can be long (ecommerce products), and because they're "centered" it could consume too much space.

On the other hand - neither amazon or ebay have title in header.

I haven't found any best practice for this, maybe you could help - or is there any greatly designed ecommerce solution for inspiration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there's the possibility of very long titles I would have them left aligned and *not* in a title bar (to allow line breaks).

**Update:** Just checked amazon.com and they do it exactly like that:

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Well, I mentioned this in question - "neither amazon or ebay have title in header". But thx, I'm probably going this way, because there is really no need to show title all the time. Users are not so dumb :)

Comment: Oops, missed that part. I think this solution works pretty well... don't really see what is has to do with the user's intelligence though ;)

Comment: Common argument for title in header (sticky) is that users should be **always** able to know where they are. But this never worked for desktops and I doubt it will for mobile devices, where every px matters even more. And as I think about it in deep, the same thing applies even for breadcrumbs - especially on iPhone, everything is just few "slides" back.

Answer (score 0):

it depend on the content..if its clear to understand,then there is no need to use title.Also you can make it optional by adding a button that hides the title..something like "full screen" when browsing on a computer.

Answer (score -2):

i think it is more preferably to put the titles on the top left side of the page, so that you can avoid any spacing constraints in case of long titles.

you can take a look at the following site that shows best 10 e-commerce sites. check the experience they may help.

http://www.top10bestwebsitehosting.com/?kw=e%2520commerce%2520website&c=11208319428&t=search&p=&m=p&a=28&gclid=CMHVpq6sjaoCFQMLfAod73zW0g

Comment: well, that link actually lists just hosting providers, I'd liek to see some well designed mobile shop. but thx.